# How right and left shift work with negative and positive numbers

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Right Shift and Left Shift operator moves all bits right and left respectively based on numbers of bits we have specified in operation.

Example:

`int x = 1` and we do `x = x >> 1`, it moves all bits right one position and places one extra bit at left as 0.

But in case of negative numbers say `x = -1`. Its binary equivalent(in integer - 32 bits) is `11111111111111111111111111111111` (32 bits)

If we move one bit right `x = x >> 1` zero is not being added at left side and after operation it is still `11111111111111111111111111111111`(32 bits).

But if we move it one bit left `x = x << 1` zero is being added at right side and it becomes `11111111111111111111111111111110`(32 bits).

Same is not true with positive numbers.

i.e. when we right shift positive number one bit zero is being added at left side whereas in case of negative numbers 1 is being added.

Comment: What is not true with positive numbers?

Comment: What's the question? You have stated facts?